# Remote Login with Credential gives PSRemotingTransportException

Tags: windows, powershell

I am just trying to write a script that can remote login with user/pass credentials via Jenkins. I wrote this script that is given below;

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "SOME_PASSWORD" -asplaintext -force
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "SOME_USERAME",$pass
invoke-command "SOME_COMPUTER_NAME" {get-process} -credential $mycred
```

After running this script it giving error like;

```
[SOME_COMPUTER_NAME] Connecting to remote server SOME_COMPUTER_NAME failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the
 WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SOME_COMPUTER_NAME:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken
```

**Before** your question and suggestions; just controlled WinRM service local and remote machines, I enabled PSRemoting and Set-Item TrustedHosts on remote machine.

Comment: Can you Create a PSSession using that credential?

`New-PSSession -ComputerName $CN -Credential $myCred -Authentication Credssp`

Comment: Actually this worked, but didn't solve my problem. After fixing this it says; Use gpedit.msc and look at the following policy: Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation -> Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials.  Verify that it is enabled and configured with an SPN appropriate for the target computer. For example, for a ta
rget computer name "myserver.domain.com", the SPN can be one of the following: WSMAN/myserver.domain.com or WSMAN/*.domain.com. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. I checked these, and everything ok

Comment: Can you update your question with what you are now doing?

Comment: This was a network problem. So, this answer is definitely helpful. Thanks a lot